# Execute SQL with "like" statement in R Language

Tags: r, rodbc

I am trying to execute a SQL Query through R to get the data from Access DB

Normal SQL statement works fine, but when it comes to like statement its throwing error

Below is code :

```
library(RODBC);
channel = odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,    *.accdb)};DBQ=C:/Users/ADMIN/Documents/R.accdb")
test = sqlQuery(channel ,paste('SELECT R.ID, R.Template, R.WEDate FROM R WHERE R.Template Like "*slow*"'))
```

Error:
[1] "07002 -3010 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2."
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT R.ID, R.Template, R.WEDate FROM R WHERE (R.Template Like \"*slow*\")'

Is there a way to fix this.

Comment: Just a thought, try using `%` instead of `*`.

Comment: @joran Still the same error

Comment: Try reversing your use of double and single quotes (single quotes on the inside, double on the outside).

Comment: @joran it didn't work as well

Comment: Not sure, must be something having to do with Access, I run `LIKE` queries like that using RODBC to other dbs all the time.

Comment: Just tried with access and I am also not having any luck with like statements

Comment: @joran can you help me with the sample of those like query's if possible

Comment: You seem to be missing a `)` right parenthesis. Though you don't seem to be pasting anything, so maybe it's the `paste(` that is extra, rather than the `)` that is missing. Also, I agree with other commenters - never used Access, but `LIKE` queries aren't a problem generally, but make sure you string is a vlid query - use single quotes internally. Looks like [in Access, `*` is used instead of `%` as a match-any wildcard](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like.php).

Comment: @Gregor I missed it when I pasted the code. I have tried % as well.

Comment: I think the problem is actually the right parenthesis in `'SELECT R.ID, R.Template, R.WEDate FROM R WHERE R.Template Like "*slow*")'`.  There is no opening to that parenthesis.  It can be removed from the query.

Comment: Also, what is `R`.  Is there actually a table in the database named `R`? (I ask because that seems more likely to be an alias than an actual table).

Comment: @Benjamin , Yes R my table in DB R. DB is Access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider **both** of @joran's suggestions with single quote enclosing string literals AND using the ANSI-92 wildcard operator `%`. You would use asterisk, `*` (ANSI-89 mode) when running an internal query, namely inside the MSAccess.exe GUI program (which defaults to DAO) or if you connect externally to Access with DAO. Meanwhile, ADO connections uses the percent symbol which most external interfaces uses including RODBC.

I was able to reproduce your issue and both these remedies worked. Also, no need to use `paste()` as you are not concatenating any other object to query statement.

```
library(RODBC);
channel = odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; 
                             DBQ=C:/Users/ADMIN/Documents/R.accdb")

test = sqlQuery(channel, 
                "SELECT R.ID, R.Template, R.WEDate FROM R WHERE R.Template Like '%slow%'")
```

Comment: this combination works well , Thanks for the Idea bro